# How can I show custom page when publishing my web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We all know when we want to upload new dll files and upgrade our web application, web get this error when opening the website:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly '****' or one of its dependencies. The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

I'm looking for a solution to handle this error and show a custom html file when dll is uploading.

Any Idea?!

Comment: Exactly how are you publishing?

Comment: I'm uploading dll files via ftp...

Comment: You should have said that. There is nothing that will magically create a page just because you're using FTP. Those who have answered you have been assuming you're  using MSDEPLOY or something a bit more modern.

Comment: can you help me to how can I publish my web site with MSDEPLOY?

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy. If you want more detail, in book form, then get http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Build-Engine-Foundation/dp/0735645248/ and maybe http://www.amazon.com/Supplement-Inside-Microsoft-Build-Engine/dp/0735678162/.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start uploading DLLs, upload an `app_offline.html` file to the root of the web application.  You can customize this however you see fit.

Remove it when your done updating your DLL files.